# how to add live updating charts in yii with highchart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, highcharts

Am using Yii and Activehighcharts to show charts.
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activehighcharts

controller is as follows

```
    public function actionChartView(){
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('ChartData',array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'dID=2',
                'order'=>'time ASC',
                ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>50,
                ),
            )
        );
        $p=$dataProvider->pagination;
        $p->setItemCount($dataProvider->getTotalItemCount());
        $p->currentPage=$p->pageCount-1;
        if(isset($_GET['json']) && $_GET['json'] == 1){
            $count = ChartData::model()->count();
            for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
                $data = ChartData::model()->findByPk($i);
                $data->data += rand(-10,10);
                $data->save();
            }
            echo CJSON::encode($dataProvider->getData());
        }
        else{
            $this->render('ChartView',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,));
        }
}
```

View as

```
 $this->Widget('ext.ActiveHighcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'template'=>'{items}',
    'id'=>'Temperature',
    'options'=> array(
        'title'=>array(
            'text'=>'Temperature'
        ),
        'chart'=>array(
            "zoomType"=>'x',
        ),
        'xAxis'=>array(
            'title' => array('text' => 'Time',),
            'categories' => 'time',
            'labels' => array(
                'rotation' => -90,
                'y'        => 20,
                ),
        ),
        'yAxis'=>array(
            'title' => array('text' => 'DegC'),
            ),
        'series'=>array(
            array(
                'type'=>'areaspline',
                'name'=>'Temperature',      //title of data
                'dataResource'=>'data',     //data resource according to datebase column
            )
        ),
    )
));
```

i need to update the chart in every 2 minutes with ajax.
also i need to get old data.

how to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax call success call back update the data in the chart using the api methods provided in highcharts documentation.

please refer this [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart) it will help you to find a good solution.

Comment: am not at all understanding how to add these things in model/controller and view.

Answer (score 0):

**Ok. To best answer your question i will try to clear things as much as possible.**

First you need to create a view (a php file that will contain your highchart code)

Second you need to edit your Controller (let's assume siteController) and create an action to call the view you've just create. Inside that action you will need to connect and query the database.

See the below sample code:

**siteController action:**

```
public function actionAtencionesMensuales() {
$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(hora) as mes, count(*) as total
FROM visitas
WHERE YEAR(hora)=YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(hora)')->queryAll();
$mes = array();
$total = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($sql); $i++) {
$mes[] = $sql[$i]["mes"];
$total[] = (int) $sql[$i]["total"];
}
$this->render('my_view', array('mes' => $mes, 'total' => $total));
}
}
```

**In the View:**

```
<?php
$this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
'options' => array(
'exporting' => array('enabled' => true),
'title' => array('text' => 'Mes'),
'theme' => 'grid',
'rangeSelector' => array('selected' => 1),
'xAxis' => array(
'categories' => $mes
),
'yAxis' => array(
'title' => array('text' => 'Cantidad')
),
'series' => array(
array('name' => 'Total', 'data' => $total = array_map('intVal', $total)),
)
)
));
?>
```

**Within the series of the chart, it's better to use when calling the variable:**

```
$total = array_map('intVal', $total)
```

**Instead of just:**

```
$total
```

**Good luck :)**